# ObjectInputStream doesn't have available bytes after being constructed with a ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java, serialization, inputstream, objectinputstream, bytearrayinputstream

I'm constructing a class that is handling a Binary De/Serialization. The method `open()` receives an `InputStream` and a `OutputStream`. Those are created by another `open()` method that receives a path as argument. The `InputStream` is actually a `ByteArrayInputStream`. 
I already did some tests to prove that the `InputStream` is arriving at the `open()` method with content - and it actually is. But when I try to set a `ObjectInputStream` using it, it doesn't work. No exceptions are thrown, but when I try to read bytes from it, it always gives me `-1`.

> BinaryStrategy class

```
public class BinaryStrategy implements SerializableStrategy{
  public BinaryStrategy(){
    try{
        open("products.ser");
    }catch(IOException ioe){

    }
  } 
  @Override
  public void open(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException  {
    try{
        this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(input);
    }catch(Exception ioe){
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
    this.oos = new ObjectOutputStream(output);
  }
  @Override
  public void writeObject(fpt.com.Product obj) throws IOException {
    oos.writeObject(obj);
    oos.flush();
  }
  @Override
  public Product readObject() throws IOException {
    Product read = new Product();
    try{
        read.readExternal(ois);
    }catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException exc){
        System.out.println(exc);
    }
    return read;
  }
}
```

> interface SerializableStrategy (just the default method)

```
    default void open(Path path) throws IOException {
    if (path != null) {
        ByteArrayInputStream in = null;
        if (Files.exists(path)) {
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }
        OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(path);
        open(in, out);
    }
```

> Product class

```
public class Product implements java.io.Externalizable {
    @Override
public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeLong(getId());
    out.writeObject(getName());
    out.writeObject(getPrice());
    out.writeObject(getQuantity());
}

@Override
public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    this.setId((Long)in.readLong());
    this.setName((String) in.readObject());
    this.setPrice((Double) in.readObject());
    this.setQuantity((Integer) in.readObject());
}
```

I had to personalize it because the attributes are `SimpleProperty`s

At `public void open(InputStream input, OutputStream output)` I tried to do some stuff as follow to test:

```
    public void open(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    try{
        System.out.println(input.available() + " " + input.read() + " " + input.read());
        //is gives me: 181 172 237
        //181 is the exact size of the file I have, so i think that the Output is ok
        //172 237 - just some chars that are in the file
        //I know that for now on it is going to give me an excepetion because
        // of the position of the index that is reading. I did it just to test
        this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(input);
    }catch(Exception ioe){
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
    this.oos = new ObjectOutputStream(output);
}
```

And then the other test:

```
public void open(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    try{
        this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(input);
        System.out.println(ois.available() + " " + ois.read());
        //here is where I am receiving -1 and 0 available bytes!
        //so something is going wrong right here.
        //i tried to just go on and try to read the object,
        //but I got a EOFException, in other words, -1.
    }catch(Exception ioe){
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
    this.oos = new ObjectOutputStream(output);
}
```

Comment: Show us the rest of the code, there is nothing we can do with only this

Comment: please show us the code where you get -1 also

Comment: There you go, just edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ObjectInputStream`, internally uses a `BlockDataInputStream` perform its read operations. This reads a block of data and not just a byte as we expect, when you call a `read`. It reads a byte only if it falls as a "block"

The output is not what I was expecting either.
But, if you look at the code of `ObjectInputStream.read()`, it makes sense.

So, in your case it makes sense to use only `readObject` to restore your objects' state.

Heres your code again...

```
class SimpleJava {

    public static void open(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {

        try {
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(input);
            System.out.println(ois.available());// 0
            System.out.println(ois.available() + " " + ois.read() + " " + ois.read());// 0 -1 -1
            // Reads the object even if the available returned 0 
            // and ois.read() returned -1
            System.out.println("object:" + ois.readObject());// object:abcd
        }
        catch (Exception ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void open(Path path) throws IOException {

        if (path != null) {
            ByteArrayInputStream in = null;
            if (Files.exists(path)) {
                byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
                in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            }
            OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(path);
            open(in, out);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/pradhan/temp.object")));
        oos.writeObject("abcd");//writes a string object for us to read later
        oos.close();
        //
        open(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("/home/user/temp.object"));
    }
}
```

Heres the output...

```
0
0 -1 -1
object:abcd
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the file represented by the `path` has a java object written to it.

 From the ObjectInputStream API doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html

> An ObjectInputStream deserializes primitive data and objects previously written using an ObjectOutputStream.
>
> ObjectInputStream is used to recover those objects previously serialized.

If you are doing a `this.ois.readObject()`, and you are getting a `-1`, there are chances that the file does not contain an object in it.

Update: `readObject` returns an object and not an `int`. If you are using the `read` methods in `ois`, and you are getting a `-1`, then the file is empty.

Also, there are chances that your file contains ***-1*** as its content ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I used the `ObjectOutputStream` to write the file that I'm trying to deserialize, so the file must contain a serialized object. As I said, the `OutputStream`, that is actually a `ByteArrayOutputStream` is carrying something. I used the `available()` and `read()` methos to prove that and it actually works.

Comment: I see that you are reading the object from the `path` and opening a `newOutputStream` on the same `path`. Note that this will clear the file.
Check if you are getting any exception while you are writing to the file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was reading the `ObjectInputStream` the wrong way. It was like:

```
read.readExternal(ois);
```

but the correct way is:

```
read = (Product)ois.readObject();
```

And beacause of the Exceptions I was getting for doing so, I thought that the problem was with the construction of `ObjectInputStream` when using `ByteArrayInputStream`.
What a big mistake! :D

Thanks to everybody that tried to help.